# Graduated Style Renderer not displaying for joined csv to shp

Tags: qgis, csv, attribute-joins, style-manager

I have joined a csv file (via the add spreadsheet layer plugin) and the field types have saved correctly (i.e. they are "real" types, see attached image), and yet the graduated style renderer option is not available. I have several numeric fields showing percentages and total numbers that I would like to display as graduated classes. Any advice? Ideas on why the graduated style option is not showing? See image of current style window. I am using QGIS version 2.18.23

[image: Field types correct]

[image: Style window without graduated renderer option]

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting Single symbol which is the default style when you click on `Layer Properties -> Style`. You need to change the `Single symbol` to `Graduated`:

[image]

Then, under `Column`, select the field that you need to show its graduated color. If you still couldn't see the numerical field under `Column`, then save your CSV file as a shapefile and try again the same steps using the shapefile.